# How to display two images in a single view - iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I need to display two images in a single view. Till now I have done only displaying a single image, but how to display two images in a single view? Is it possible in iPhone? If so can you please guide me how to?

Note: I need to show both the images same time.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean a bit. Or put a drawing of what you want. There are many ways to do this.

Comment: @Fogmeister In a single view I need to show two images with some text below the images. These images are taken frm camera. An it will be in session.

Comment: The two images will be displayed at the same time?

Comment: @sanjit shaw yes need to show both the images same time.

Comment: Could you give an example that how would you like to display both if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIImageView *imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
UIImageView *imgView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 110, 100, 50)];
imgView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
imgView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imgView1];
[self.view addSubview:imgView2];
```

Comment: Will this display images in parallel. I am not getting any response after aqdding this code?

Comment: You can set the proper frame sizes to display the images next to one another.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to overlap 2 images then paste this code ,

```
        UIImage *a = [ your 1st iamge];
        UIImage *b = [ your 2nd iamge];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(a.size);
        [a drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, a.size.width, a.size.height)];
        [b drawInRect:CGRectMake(a.size.width - b.size.width, a.size.height - b.size.height, b.size.width, b.size.height)];
        UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [YourImageView setImage:result];
```

Comment: thanks.. It might be useful in feauture for some googlers... I solved the problem by the above answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either 
- 2 instances of `UIImageView`, and layout them as needed;
- or subclass `UIView` and draw 2 `UIImage`s by overriding `drawInRect:`

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)displayImages
{
    UIImageView *firstImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage"]];
    firstImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    UIImageView *secondImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage"]];
    secondImage.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 100);
    [self.view addSubview:firstImage];
    [self.view addSubview:secondImage];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by just adding two `UIImageViews` into the view.

If you're already displaying one `UIImageView` then just add another and put the second image in that one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to merge both images

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (MyImage)


+ (UIImage*)imageFromView:(UIView*)view;
+ (UIImage*)imageFromView:(UIView*)view scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
+ (void)beginImageContextWithSize:(CGSize)size;
+ (UIImage *)croppedImage:(UIImage *)myImage :(CGRect)bounds;

//masking the image ....

+ (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "UIImage+MyImage.h"

@implementation UIImage (MyImage)

+ (void)beginImageContextWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 2.0);
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
        }
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    }
}

+ (void)endImageContext
{
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

+ (UIImage*)imageFromView:(UIView*)view
{
    [self beginImageContextWithSize:[view bounds].size];
    BOOL hidden = [view isHidden];
    [view setHidden:NO];
    [[view layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self endImageContext];
    [view setHidden:hidden];
    return image;
}

+ (UIImage*)imageFromView:(UIView*)view scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIImage *image = [self imageFromView:view];
    if ([view bounds].size.width != newSize.width ||
        [view bounds].size.height != newSize.height) {
        image = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:newSize];
    }
    return image;
}

+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    [self beginImageContextWithSize:newSize];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self endImageContext];
    return newImage;
}


+ (UIImage *)croppedImage:(UIImage *)myImage :(CGRect)bounds {
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(myImage.CGImage, bounds);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGSize asd =  croppedImage.size;
    return croppedImage;
}




+ (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);

    CGImageRelease(mask);
    CGImageRelease(maskRef);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}



@end
```

Comment: Can make image to display in parallel. means asume two images near by near. Not one below the other.